# How to test multiple classes (one interface) with multiple params in?

Tags: java, unit-testing, tdd, junit4

I have multiple classes that implement one interface and I want to test their methods with multiple test cases.

This is my test method that tests only one class with multiple parameters. How to use it with multiple classes and multiple parameters?

```
@RunWith(value = Parameterized.class)
public class CoinFactory_getCoin {
    private final int in;
    private final int out;

    public CoinFactory_getCoin(final int in, final int out) {
        this.in = in;
        this.out = out;
    }

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        final Object[][] data = new Object[][] { { 1, 0 }, { 2, 1 },
                { 5, 2 }, { 10, 5 },
                { 20, 10 },
                { 50, 20 }, { 100, 50 }, { 200, 100 } };
        return Arrays.asList(data);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_normal_parameters() {

        // given
        final CoinFactory factory = new CoinFactory();

        // when
        final int nextCoin = factory.getNextCoin(in);

        // then
        Assertions.assertThat(nextCoin).isEqualTo(out);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could make the test-class abstract, and add an abstract method that returns the instance of the CoinFactory you want to test. Every extending Test-class could provide its very own `static data()` method.

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple paramters", different types or different count?

Comment: Different count. For example I have method int fibonacci(int idx) which gives me value of f-number on idx position and I want to test it for these in parameters: {1, 2, 10, 100}

Comment: You have multiple parameters - in and out.  Can you elaborate on what you meant by this?